# facebook application post on user's wall with permission(publish/skip) php sdk

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

i am creating a facebook application. i have managed an extended publish stream application. and i want to display the app results on user's wall. doing the method below, it automatically posts on the user's wall, i want to do it through the publish/skip dialog. could anyone please help me. thanks a lot!!

```
        $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'post', array(
        'message' => message,
        'name' => $fbme['first_name'],
        'description' => 'here goes description',
        'caption' => 'this is caption',
        'picture' => $imageurl,
        'link' => 'some link here',
```

//the next part, inviting friends. i want when the user clicks publish/skip only then a dialog window to apper to request to invite friends. i try it this way, but it does not work.

```
function(response) {
 if (response && response.post_id) {
   alert('Post was published.');
   '<?php echo("invitefriends.php")'
 } else {
   alert('Post was not published.');
   '<?php echo("invitefriends.php")' 
 }
```

the problem i have is i get three windows and all of them simultaneously. invitefriends.php has the same code as mentioned in the javascript sdk example and it works fine.

let me know where and how to include invitefriends.php.

thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you can use FB's JS API

You can follow this tutorial

http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/graph-api-iframe-base-facebook-application-development/

Comment: thnx the above link is helpful indeed, but it does not solve my problem, check the comment above.

Answer (score 3):

You should use [`FB.ui`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/fb.ui/):

```
 FB.ui(
   {
     method: 'feed',
     name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
     link: 'http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/',
     picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
     caption: 'Reference Documentation',
     description: 'Dialogs provide a simple, consistent interface for applications to interface with users.',
     message: 'Facebook Dialogs are easy!'
   },
   function(response) {
     if (response && response.post_id) {
       alert('Post was published.');
     } else {
       alert('Post was not published.');
     }
   }
 );
```

To test this, go to the [**Test Console**](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/console/) -> Click on the **Examples** -> And then from the **fb.ui** list choose **feed**.

Comment: thanks ifaour, i have seen this in the fb documentation and had implemented it as well, but the problem is : all of my messages are different. i.e. they take data from mysql table as a php variable. so i have different imageurls for different messages. say in fetchdata.php i get the url from mysql table. and say i am updating status in statusupdate.php ... when i write **picture: $imageurl** ... it shows an error and it goes for all the params i.e. links, message etc.  hope you get my problem. thnx !

Comment: @RahulSharma: Can you provide the code that is giving you the error? also you are aware that you should use something like `picture: '<?php echo $imageurl; ?>',` right?

Comment: thnx man. i was making a silly mistake of adding extra quote. just one more issue, see the change in your code, that is yet another doubt!! –

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but you as long as  i can guess you need access token to post on user wall.

$token = $facebook->getAccesstoken();

```
$facebook->api('/me/feed', 'post', array(
    'message' => message,
    'name' => $fbme['first_name'],
    'description' => 'here goes description',
    'caption' => 'this is caption',
    'picture' => $imageurl,
    'link' => 'some link here',
    'access_token' =>$toekn);
```

i hope it